# Using the Wizard in Overpass Turbo to download all layers within the Bounding-Box

Tags: overpass-api

I am using the Bounding-Box and the wizard query to download data from [Overpass Turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/#).
I am using the id [openStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?editor=id#map=14/32.9081/35.1944) editor to find the right query word, and it is working great.
However, I was wondering is there a way do download all the data from the bounding box without the necessity of run each layer separately?
I was looking in the [Overpass API/Language Guide](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Sample_map_calls), but I did not find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, OSM doesn't have a concept of a "layer". What you're looking for is the map export function: https://www.openstreetmap.org/export  -> Select bounding box -> Click on the Overpass API link.

Note: don't use the "Export" button, as it is based on a different mechanism which is limited to 50'000 nodes.

In general you should first check, if there are existing extracts available for your area, as this is way more efficient and recommended for larger areas. See http://download.geofabrik.de/ as an example